# In Aurelia, how to set checkbox for multi-select to unchecked after event occurs

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have a ListView component that has a checkbox that allows you to do a check-all at once. It's bound to this.selectAll on the component class. There's a toggle method that get's called when it's checked.

```
<checkbox-input checked.bind="selectAll"></checkbox-input>

toggleAll()
    {
        this.items.forEach( item =>
        {
            item.selected = this.selectAll;
        });
        this.showHideToolbar();
    }
```

On the Toolbar it allows the user to perform actions on the items in the list.

After the action is performed the items are individually unchecked but then the selectAll checkbox is always still checked.

I would like to make so that when the toolbar user does some action on the list that it unchecks the select all if all the items are no longer selected or if all the items are removed from the list.

Edit: I solved it by checking in the showHideToolbar method for anyChecked to set the this.selectAll when nothing was checked to false.

Comment: It would help a lot if you can provide a gist.run, or something similar, with a [minimal and complete sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); I myself am not really sure what your current and expected behaviour is.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out what I needed to do. I needed to check if this.selectAll was set in the showHideToolbar() method then check if any of the items in the list were selected. If there was anyChecked then it remains checked else it becomes unchecked.